# How to add login with amazon button to Asp.net Mvc site

Tags: amazon-web-services

How to add login with amazon button to asp.net mvc site?
https://login.amazon.com/website

Answer (score 0):

ASP.net is a server side rendering technology.  Login With Amazon is just relying on client side Javascript to be included in your HTML.  So following the steps indicated here will work with any server side tech : PHP, ASP, JSP etc ...
https://login.amazon.com/website

It is recommended that the server side handle the access token.  Once your server will receive the access token, you can cann Amazon profile API to fetch user's details.  Examples are given on step 4 in different languages (PHP, Java, Pyton and NodeJS) These are using a simple HTTPS call to the Amazon Proile API, it will be easy to adapt any of these example to ASP.net

This article list several methods to call REST API from C# https://code-maze.com/different-ways-consume-restful-api-csharp/